# tweeting using "@" and "#" through tweeter api

Tags: rest, twitter, postman, sttwitterapi

I am new to tweeter api(beginner level experience), have been exploring tweeter rest api. so far I managed to read user timeline, followers count and also able to tweet.

However in a tweet, I wish to mention users by using "@" symbol.
example something like this.

[image: This is how I am Entering mentions]

This is not working,  also the same case with hashtags "#"
getting error as 
[image: Error when @ is used]

If I remove "@", then it works and posts a message.

Also referred the reference api https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update

However neither could i figure out any relevant parameter that I can use nor able to find any example while surfing.

For this POC, Twitter standard api is used(Just thinking if this feature is allowed in standard api)

Thanks and appreciate any advice/guidance

Ashish

Comment: Have you tried updating your older version of Postman and trying it? The URL encoding has changed a lot since then.

Comment: true...it is working in new postman application however not in old postman application with the same procedure.
thanks @DannyDainton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way that Postman is encoding your request, which breaks OAuth 1.0A for Twitter. You can try the following:

- Disable all params in Params tab
- Open Body tab and click `x-www-form-urlencoded`, then add params as needed

Comment: thanks @AndyPiper, my mistake was adding "status" parameter in params tab. As per your suggestion I added the same in x-www-form-urlencoded marked body and it worked like a charm.
appreciate your time